# React Native: Change the Entry file path index.android.js to specified custom file path

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I need to change the Entry file path to **src/XXXApp.android.js** instead of pointing to default index.android.js file. I want to keep the JS file in seperate ./src folder.

So that I made the change in **./android/app/build.gradle** like

```
 project.ext.react = [
    bundleAssetName: "src/XXXApp.android.bundle",
    entryFile: file("../../src/XXXApp.android.js"),
    root: "../../../../",
    inputExcludes: ["android/**", "./**"]
 ]
```

and in **.\node_modules\react-native\react.gradle** file like

```
def bundleAssetName = config.bundleAssetName ?:"src/XXXApp.android.bundle"
def entryFile = config.entryFile ?: "src/XXXApp.android.js"
```

But development package server always pointing to **localhost:8081/index.android/bundle.** . Manually i tried the URL: **localhost:8081/src/XXXApp.android.bundle** and it retrieve the data.
But in device debug loadJs always try the **localhost:8081/index.android/bundle.**

Please share the solution, proper place to update the entry file config for android. Appreciate in advance for your valuable solution.

Answer (score 3):

In your MainActivity you can override getJSBundleFile() method of ReactActivity. Here you can specify your bundle file name along with the path. Code push use same method of override reactjs bundle path.

Comment: in rn 0.35, the getJSBundleFile() had been removed from ReactActivity. so you need to implement getJSBundleFile()  and/or getBundleAssetName in implementation of ReactNativeHost(), typically in your customized application